# If $|P_{n+1}-q|\le c|P_n - q|$ for all $n$, where $c<1$, then $P_n\to q$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given $|P_{n+1}-q|\le c|P_n - q|$ for all $n$, where $c<1$ show that the

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P_n=q.$$

Was told to complete this problem by iteration. I'm terrible with proofs and they don't make sense to me. If any can and is willing I would love a complete break down on this problem.

Comment: Begin by proving that $|P_n-q|\le c^{n-1}|P_1-q|$, by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Two hints:

What can you say about $|P_{n+2}-q|$? (Compare it to $|P_{n+1}-q|$ then to $|P_{n}-q|$.) Then what can you say about $|P_{n+3}-q|$, etc.?

What can you say about $c^n$ as $n$ increases to infinity?